# PhpStorm / SFTP Connection "auth fails"

Tags: phpstorm, sftp

I'm having a problem connecting to one specific SFTP Server. Auth is user & pwd. Can somebody make something out of the log files?

I'm new to PhpStorm - its pretty cool, but if it's not working, I would need to change back to my old stuff

```
2017-01-09 09:46:33,147 [  30133]  DEBUG - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Opening connection to sftp://www.mysftpserver.at:22/ in @77287eb7 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,158 [  30144]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Connecting to www.mysftpserver.at port 22 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,213 [  30199]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Connection established 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,278 [  30264]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-mod_sftp/0.9.9 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,278 [  30264]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,278 [  30264]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,280 [  30266]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes256-ctr is not available. 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,280 [  30266]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes192-ctr is not available. 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,280 [  30266]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes256-cbc is not available. 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,280 [  30266]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes192-cbc is not available. 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,280 [  30266]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,308 [  30294]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,rsa1024-sha1 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-ctr,3des-cbc 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-ctr,3des-cbc 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,umac-64@openssh.com 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,umac-64@openssh.com 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server:  
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server:  
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: none 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,309 [  30295]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: none 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,310 [  30296]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client:  
2017-01-09 09:46:33,310 [  30296]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client:  
2017-01-09 09:46:33,310 [  30296]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,310 [  30296]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,313 [  30299]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,314 [  30300]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,368 [  30354]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,368 [  30354]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Host 'www.mysftpserver.at' is known and matches the RSA host key 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,368 [  30354]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,373 [  30359]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,375 [  30361]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,417 [  30403]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,462 [  30448]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,462 [  30448]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive 
2017-01-09 09:46:33,518 [  30504]   WARN - Deployment.config.SftpUserInfo - Unsupported keyboard interactive request: destination="myusername@www.mysftpserver.at", name="", instruction="", prompt=["Passwort: "] 
2017-01-09 09:46:35,687 [  32673]   WARN - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA. 
2017-01-09 09:46:35,756 [  32742]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Authentications that can continue: password 
2017-01-09 09:46:35,756 [  32742]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Next authentication method: password 
2017-01-09 09:46:35,757 [  32743]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Login trials exceeds 1 
2017-01-09 09:46:35,757 [  32743]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Disconnecting from www.mysftpserver.at port 22 
2017-01-09 09:46:35,760 [  32746]   WARN - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Retrying connecting to sftp://www.mysftpserver.at:22/ in @77287eb7: 1 iterations 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://www.mysftpserver.at/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:712)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:186)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:115)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeContext.getConnection(ServerTreeContext.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.computeFile(ServerTreeNode.java:274)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.createChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:179)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.loadChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:164)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.lambda$getChildren$0(ServerTreeNode.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "www.mysftpserver.at".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:182)
    ... 19 more
2017-01-09 09:46:35,764 [  32750]   WARN - i.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode - Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://www.mysftpserver.at/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://www.mysftpserver.at/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:712)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:186)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:115)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeContext.getConnection(ServerTreeContext.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.computeFile(ServerTreeNode.java:274)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.createChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:179)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.loadChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:164)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.lambda$getChildren$0(ServerTreeNode.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "www.mysftpserver.at".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:182)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: For ref purposes (the same on WebStorm forums): https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000018710-SFTP-Connection-Auth-Failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPStorm already answered my and the fixed the bug. See their reply:

> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34664 is fixed, fix can be expected in next EAP

Comment: They fixed the bug in the official relase!

Comment: this is solution will work for versions older than **2017.1.4**